# AngularUI Typeahead triggers ng-blur function twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to validate a angular ui typeahead (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) field. My problem is that my validation function is triggered on blur, however the act of selecting an option from the drop down counts as a blur, so my function is triggering twice, once when they select from the drop down and again as they leave the field.

The first time, it throws an error since it is validating the incomplete field before the user selected the field that they want. Then it triggers again and finishes validating when they actually leave the field.

I want to skip the validation that happens on the selection from the drop down, so ONLY validate once the user has completely left the field. I tried executing the function using typeahead-on-select but it wasn't working the way I hoped, I think it's use is for something else but tell me if I am wrong.

The validation is checking to see if the value in the field matches what is in a list that was retrieved on load:

```
$scope.validateNumber = function() {
                for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myList.length; i++) {
                    console.log($scope.myForm.mynumber.$viewValue);
                    console.log($scope.myList[i].myfield);
                    if ($scope.myForm.mynumber.$viewValue !== $scope.myList[i].CustNo) {
                        console.log('they do NOT match!');

                        $scope.myForm.mynumber.$setValidity("valid", false);

                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('they do match!');
                        $scope.myForm.mynumber.$setValidity("valid", true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
```

Here is the template for the typeahead. As you can see, I call the function above using ng-blur. I cannot use ng-model-options on blur because then the typeahead won't work, as it needs to update as the model changes.

```
                          <input othervalidationdirective
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control input-sm"
                           id="mynumber"
                           name="mynumber"
                           ng-model="myinfo.myfield"
                           ng-change="otherfield = null"
                           ng-blur="validateNumber()"
                           uib-typeahead="option as option.MyValue for option in myList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
                           typeahead-template-url="/tpl.html"
                           typeahead-loading="loading"
                           typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, 10)"
                           typeahead-min-length="2"
                           typeahead-no-results="noResults"
                           required>
```

Answer (score -2):

add timeout to onBlur function.

```
function onBlurFunction(){
  $timeout(function(){ 
    //some code
  }, 300);
};
```